# setState is not working on 2nd time calling it inside componentDIdMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im a beginner, im trying to make a memory game
this component fetches data for an api
then trims it down with only that has image link

then on level one it should display 3 random image from fetch data
it always
displayedChars: [undefined, undefined, undefined]

```
    constructor(props) {
       super()
       this.state = {
             level: 1,
             numImg: 1*3,
             displayedChars: [],
             chars: []
       }

    }


      async componentDidMount() {
        await this.loadData().then(data => {
          this.setState({
            chars: this.trimData(data)
          });
        });
    
        await this.displayChars().then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          this.setState({
            displayedChars: data
          });
        });
        
        console.log(this.state);
      }

     async loadData() {
       try {
         const res = await fetch(`http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters`)
         const characters = await res.json();
         return characters
       } catch(err) {
         console.error(err)
       }
     }

     trimData(characters) {
       const listChars = []
         characters.map(char => {
           if(char.image !== "") {
             listChars.push(char)
           }
         })
         return listChars
     }

     displayChars() {
         return (new Promise((resolve) => {
           const list = []
           for(let x=1; x<= this.state.numImg; x++) {
             let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24);
             list.push(this.state.chars[randomNum]);
           }
           console.log(list)
           resolve(list)
         }))

    }
```

in the this.displayChars()
console.log(data) works fine
but

```
          this.setState({
            displayedChars: data
          });
```

then console.log(this.state)
OUTPUT: [undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: The first `setState` call will reset the whole state object to `chars: this.trimData(data)`, i.e. the `numImg` property won't exist, but it's needed for the `displayChars` function to work. You need to use the spread operator to update your state instead of resetting it: `this.setState({...this.state, chars: this.trimData(data)});`

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, so you cannot see the updated states immediately, that's why your `console.log` is `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. You can assign variables to handle responses separately instead of using `this.state`.

The second concern is you shouldn't mix `then` and async/await. I'd prefer using async/await alone in your case.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const chars = await this.loadData();
        const displayedChars = await this.displayChars();
        
        this.setState({
            displayedChars: displayedChars
            chars: this.trimData(chars)
        });
        
        //states are not updated right away
        //console.log(this.state);

        //access via variable
        console.log({ chars, displayedChars })
      }
```